# Bootstrap progress bar not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please forgive me for asking this question if the answer is simple.  I have no idea why the progress bar isn't showing up!

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenmandy/ja26pgh1/) that has code for 2 Bootstrap progress bars. One shows up via simple HTML, but the one I'm trying to create in my project is created via jQuery by constructing HTML.  In the fiddle, you can see that only one is showing.  Can someone please help me understand why the second one is not showing up?!  Even the HTML I'm creating within the provider's div is not showing up.

HTML:

```
 <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table" border=1>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Run Id:</strong>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="runuid"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Status:</strong>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="status"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Started:</strong>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="started"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Run by:</strong>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="user"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Provider:</strong>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="providers"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var taskDiv = '<div><table border=1 class="table table-condensed">';
var progress = 47;
taskDiv += ('<tr><td>link</td><td>200min</td><td>result size</td></tr>');
taskDiv += ('<tr><td colspan="3"><div class="container"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div></div></td></tr>');
var $bar = $('.progress-bar');

if ( $bar.width() == 100 ) {
    $( '.progress' ).removeClass( 'active' );
} else {
    $bar.width(progress);
}
    $bar.text(progress + "%");
}
taskDiv+=('</table></div>');
$(taskDiv).appendTo('#providers');
$providersDiv.append('</table>');
```

Comment: You're appending a closing `</table>` tag to providersDiv. What is is providersDiv?

Comment: Also, you have some bracket issues in your `if ($bar.width()==100)` statement

Comment: Check the console on your fiddle: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.  And it's missing jquery.  Fixing those shows **two** progress bars - one gets changed to 47%, the other is at *0* (so looks like it's not there. Not sure what else it's *supposed* to do or what the actual problem is other than a couple of typos: https://jsfiddle.net/ja26pgh1/1/

Comment: Updated fiddle so 2nd bar isn't on 0 so you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/ja26pgh1/2/

Comment: If you're expecting the 2nd bar to be at 47%, then you might like to add it to the DOM before you make DOM changes...